# Watch File Directory Change Multiple Lines Return

Tags: python-3.x

Python returns more than one entry when running this code. Not sure why it doesnt run just once.

I tried changing the sleep time but am not sure whats happening here.

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from subprocess import call

class Watcher:
    DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = r"C:\Users\tgaluska\File"

    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()

    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(5)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
            print ("Error")
        self.observer.join()

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
     def on_any_event(self,event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None
        elif event.event_type == 'modified':
            print ("Received modified event - %s." % event.src_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        w = Watcher()
        w.run()

Received modified event - C:\Users\tg\File\Superstore.xls.
Received modified event - C:\Users\tg\File\Superstore.xls.
Received modified event - C:\Users\tg\File\Superstore.xls.
Received modified event - C:\Users\tg\File\Superstore.xls.
Received modified event - C:\Users\tg\File\Superstore.xls.
Received modified event - C:\Users\tg\File\Superstore.xls.
```

On Line

Received modified event - C:\Users\tg\File\Superstore.xls.

Comment: It's a little strange to be defining classes inside a `with` - not sure if it's related, but I'd define the classes at the top level, then put the class instantiation (`w = Watcher()` etc)  inside the `with` block instead.

Comment: After reading your reply I made some small changes.

Comment: The line is only generating three times now. I added the actual process to be executed and check the server log. It runs three times. Sorry I am probably not understanding exactly what you are saying this is my first python script on an actual business case. If you have any more recommendations I would appreciate it.

Comment: elif event.event_type == 'modified':
with TM1Service(**config['Sun Fun']) as tm1:
tm1.processes.execute(“Load_Future”,parameters=None)

Comment: If you're changing code, edit the original answer, as comments don't format code nicely. What I meant was that it's unusual to do `with x as y: class z` since then the class is only set up after the `with` is running, and might be destroyed/removed when the `with` exits. The `with` should wrap around the actual instantiation/execution of the class, i.t the stuff in your `__main__` test.

Comment: match, So I removed the with statement and just had the statement print. It prints seven times now. Any ideas what else could be causing the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the code now, it runs continually due to the `while True` after the handler has been set up. It looks like there are 7 modify events happening here for that line to print 7 times?

Comment: Yeah that is the strange part. I only copied a new version of the file once. Everytime I move a new version of the file to the directory in the code it prints 7 times. Since it's one file I was assuming one print line would display.